# Inside ngOnInit() subscribing a url through service and getting a ID which eventually has to be passed to diff method in same ngOnInit()

Tags: node.js, angular7, angular-services, angular-httpclient, ansible-awx

First, I was trying to hit a url through a service and calling that service in a component.ts (ngOnInit()) and getting a ID from that first url.

Second, I had to pass the ID that i got from the first call to the other url through service method and get some information regarding that too in same component.ts( ngOnInit()).

I tried using subscribe inside subscribe but when the second url is being hit it was giving undefined value for ID. but in ngOnInit it was consoling the output

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.username= this.data.username;
    this.password= this.data.password;
    this.projectservice.getjobidlist(this.username,this.password).subscribe(data1=>{
        this.id=data1.results[0].id;
        this.idservice.id=this.id;
      console.log("inside subscribe",this.id);
      this.projectservice.getjobslists(this.username,this.password,this.idservice.id).subscribe(data=>{this.jobs=data; console.log("jobs list",this.jobs)});
    })};
```

**this is the second method code**

```
getjobslists(username,password,id){
    let credentials = username + ":" + password;
    let basic = "Basic " + btoa(credentials);
    console.log(basic);
    console.log("id in joblists",id);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'id': id,
      'authorization': basic,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });
    let options = ({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:4600/getjobdetailsfinal', options);
  }
```

**this is the nodejs for http://localhost:4600/getjobdetailsfinal**

```
app.get('/getjobdetailsfinal',function(req,res){
    id = req.headers.id;
    console.log("jobdetailsfinal",id);
    authorization = req.headers.authorization;
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': authorization
        }
    };
    url = "http://162.70.211.74/api/v1/jobs/?created_by="+id;
    console.log("this is ",url);
    axios.get(url, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("this is get for jobdetails",JSON.stringify(response.data))
            res.send(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
})
```

I was getting undefined in console.log(id) 3rd line of nodejs code.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));` in the `app.get('/getjobdetailsfinal', `, does the id appear there? Are you using an angular proxy?

Comment: ya even though i added id in the header i can see them in the headers. why is that happened

Comment: Do you have declared a `proxy.conf.json` ?